# How to make make a conditional for a HAML class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, haml

I have a page with tabs A, B, and C, each containing a list of 'things'. When I create a new 'thing' I specify whether it is part of list A, B, or C. I would like to have the appropriate tag active after the new 'thing' is saved and there is a page refresh.

Here is my tabs HAML

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active 
    %a{href:"#a", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "A things"
  %li
    %a{href:"#b", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "B things"
  %li
    %a{href:"#c", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "C things"

.tab-content
  #a.tab-pane.fade.in.active
    "tab data"
  #b.tab-pane.fade.in
    "tab data"
  #c.tab-pane.fade.in
    "tab data"
```

How can I write a ruby conditional that will put the `active` class, which is currently hard coded on tab "a", on the tab which I just added data to?

Comment: are a,b, and c objects that we can iterate on? or just strings like a menu? cause if it is it could be done as a helper in a loop and that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

Controller:

```
class ThingsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @active_tab = *some logic to get the tab*
    # create logic
  end
end
```

View:

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li{class: @active_tab.nil? || @active_tab == "A" ? "active : ""}
    %a{href:"#a", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "A things"
  %li{class: @active_tab == "B" ? "active : ""}
    %a{href:"#b", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "B things"
  %li{class: @active_tab == "C" ? "active : ""}
    %a{href:"#c", :"data-toggle" => "tab"}
      "C things"
.tab-content
  %a.tab-pane.fade.in{class: @active_tab.nil? || @active_tab == "A" ? "active : ""}
    "tab data"
  %b.tab-pane.fade.in{class: @active_tab == "B" ? "active : ""}
    "tab data"
  %c.tab-pane.fade.in{class: @active_tab == "C" ? "active : ""}
    "tab data"
```

Would work better using an array though.

Comment: thank you. can you suggest specific controller logic?

Comment: "When I create a new 'thing' I specify whether it is part of list A, B, or C." I imagine this is a column of some sort? Set it to that?

Comment: A better condition for the class would be `class: ('active' if @active_tab == 'A')`

Comment: yes @MohammadAbuShady that is what I came up with based off of DickieBoys's suggestion and it is the clearest way to write it. Thank you